# Generic multi threaded quicksort java

Tags: java, multithreading, quicksort

I have been given an assignment to modify quicksort program in such a way so it uses generics and its multi threaded. The problem i have with the code is that it takes longer for the Multi threaded Integer quicksort call to finish, compared to the non-threaded one.

This is my implementation of both - non threaded and multi threaded  and I have a problem finding the mistake I have done.

```
class GenericQuicksort {

private static void swap(Comparable[] array, int i, int j) {
    Comparable temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

public static Comparable[] quickSort(Comparable[] array) {
    return qs(array, 0, array.length - 1);
}

private static Comparable[] qs(Comparable[] array, int left, int righ) {
    int i = left;
    int j = righ;
    Comparable pivot = array[(left + righ) / 2];
    do {
        while ((array[i].compareTo(pivot) == -1) && (i < righ)) i++;
        while ((pivot.compareTo(array[j]) == -1) && (j > left)) j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(array, i++, j--);
        }
    } while (i <= j);
    if (left < j) qs(array, left, j);
    if (i < righ) qs(array, i, righ);
    return array;
}

public static Comparable[] quickSortMulti(Comparable[] array) {
    GsMultiThread gsMultiThread = new GsMultiThread(array, 0, array.length - 1, 0);
    gsMultiThread.start(); //Not needed to start a new thread.
    try {
        gsMultiThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return array;
}

static class GsMultiThread extends Thread {

    Comparable[] array;
    int left;
    int right;
    int ii;

    public GsMultiThread(Comparable[] array, int left, int right, int i) {
        this.array = array;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.ii = ++i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = left;
        int j = right;
        Comparable pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];
        do {
            while ((array[i].compareTo(pivot) == -1) && (i < right)) i++;
            while ((pivot.compareTo(array[j]) == -1) && (j > left)) j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                swap(array, i++, j--);
            }
        } while (i <= j);
        GsMultiThread threada = null;
        GsMultiThread threadb = null;
        if (left < j) {
            if (i > 2) {
                qs(array, left, j);
            } else {
                threada = new GsMultiThread(array, left, j, ii);
                threada.start();
            }
        }
        if (i < right) {
            if (i > 2) {
                qs(array, i, right);
            } else {
                threadb = new GsMultiThread(array, i, right, ii);
                threadb.run();
            }
        }
        try {
            if (threada != null)
                threada.join();
            if (threadb != null)
                threadb.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: First things first, don't extends `Thread`. But more importantly, you can't just spin up thousands of threads and make things "faster". If you want to see speed improvements rather than just use threads for an academic exercise you'll need to learn a lot more. Here are two topics to read about: 1) thread pooling and 2) fork join.

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule that a multi threaded implementation will be faster.

Comment: Starting threads takes time. In order to see the overall speed up improvements using multiple threads you will need to test with reasonable large data sets. Doing correct benchmarking is an art of its own btw.

Comment: @GhostCat I don't think measurement is the problem, the algorithm spins up threads for the leaf tasks - that's never going to end well.

Comment: I am just saying that measurements alone is a difficult activity that a lot of people get wrong.